# Error #1009 when using AS3 bluetooth ANE

Tags: android, actionscript-3, bluetooth, flashdevelop

I want to make an android app using Bluetooth, and after some research I came across [this](http://as3breeze.com/bluetooth-ane/)
ANE. I haven't ever used an ANE, but from what I understand its implementation is very similar to using a SWC. 
 After copying the ANE to the .\lib path and including it in my project, I tried scanning for devices as suggested on the website:

```
if (Bluetooth.isSupported) {
                trace("1!");
                bt = Bluetooth.currentAdapter();
                trace("2!");
                bt.addEventListener(BluetoothScanEvent.BLUETOOTH_DISCOVERY_STARTED, bluetoothScanEventHandeler);
                bt.addEventListener(BluetoothScanEvent.BLUETOOTH_DEVICE_FOUND, bluetoothScanEventHandeler);
                bt.addEventListener(BluetoothScanEvent.BLUETOOTH_DISCOVERY_FINISHED, bluetoothScanEventHandeler);
                bt.scanForVisibleDevices();
            }
```

For some reason I get the error

```
Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
```

The traces I included point to `bt = Bluetooth.currentAdapter();` but if I change `Bluetooth.isSupported` to `Bluetooth.isSupported()` then I get the same error there. 
I've made sure that the project's Adobe AIR Application Descriptor File Template (application xmlns) matches the ANE's. 
No one else seems to have the same problem, help?

Comment: Are you including the ANEs in the project itself? Not sure how it is in Flash Builder, but you have to add the ANE to the project and then in the properties for the project, select to include it for the proper platforms, otherwise it is not packaged with the app

Comment: Yes, I've included it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are using flash develop which I am not familiar with but it sounds like BlueTooth is null. Usually ANEs are singletons and have a getInstance() method. Once you create your single instance, BlueTooth should no longer be null and you should be able to access the rest of its methods.

In your project you would usually access the ANE like..

```
var blueTooth:BlueTooth = Bluetooth.getInstance();
if(BlueTooth.isSupported)
{
}
```

or

```
if(BlueTooth.isSupported)
{
   bt = BlueTooth.getInstance().currentAdapter();
}
```

Comment: On most ANEs (including this one), `isSupported` is a `static` getter. So they are right in using `BlueTooth.isSupported`

Comment: I agree, but he said it crashed on getAdapter() not the isSupported() method. I still think he may be initializing BlueTooth incorrectly. It makes sense that BlueTooth would be null if you don't call its getInstance() method.

Comment: Nope, `Error: Call to a possibly undefined method getInstance through a reference with static type Class.`

Comment: Ok so apparently this ANE class is not a singleton. Have you tried just creating a new instance of the BlueTooth class then?

Comment: I just saw the docs and looks like you have it set up correctly in your first example. Can you verify if BlueTooth is null or the currentAdapter() method is the one returning null?

Comment: Creating a new instance of Bluetooth(); using the SecureUUID and InsecureUUID from getAdapter() returns `Error: You can not create instance of bluetooth, instead get the currentAdapter: var bluetooth:Bluetooth = Bluetooth.currentAdapter();`, so no luck there. Also apparently Bluetooth isn't null. It's the currentAdaptor() method.

Comment: I guess the blueToothAdapter can not be found on your device then. Maybe the device you are using does not support it or a bluetooth device is not properly connected. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.